# What tools can be used to keep track of changes on web pages?

Tags: website, rss, monitoring

What software or online service could one use to keep track of changes that occur on a given web page?

It would be nice to get an RSS feed for updates but other notification methods are fine too. Also more advanced logic that tries to ignore ads and other dynamic and irrelevant content would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

[Update scanner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3362) is a Firefox add-on which does just that.

> Monitors web pages for updates. Useful
>   for websites that don't provide Atom
>   or RSS feeds.
>
> Features:
>
> - Select how often each site will be scanned
> - Changes to pages are highlighted automatically
> - Minor changes can be ignored
> - Full international support

Comment: Unfortunately I happen to use Safari instead of Firefox but otherwise this seems quite nice. +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite happy with [Follow That Page](http://www.followthatpage.com/). It's good for pages that rarely change as it only scans once a day. (You can ask it to scan one URL hourly.)

You get an email message when a page changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can give these a shot:

http://www.changealarm.com/

http://www.changedetection.com/

Comment: changealarm.com doesn't work, but changedetection.com is excellent!

Comment: [http://watchthatpage.com/](http://watchthatpage.com/) is also useful but I prefer Update Scanner nowadays.